# MoveWindow : need to create Pointer from ProcessImpl.handle field

Tags: java, jna

I need to MoveWindow for an explorer process created using `ProccessBuilder`

I am using native method
    boolean MoveWindow(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight,
                               boolean bRepaint);

But, I'm missing `Pointer hWnd` value.
How can i fetch `Pointer hWnd` value from `ProcessImpl` which has a `handle` field?

Answer (score 0):

If the `ProcessImpl` handle is a window handle, then use it directly.  You can always map `MoveWindow` with a slightly different signature, i.e. `HANDLE` as the first argument type.